# How does the Array.prototype.includes function compare objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

In ECMA Specs we read that [`Array.prototype.includes`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.includes) uses [SameValueZero](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-samevaluezero) algorithm when comparing if an array includes given element.
This algorithm, when the element is an Object, it uses [SameValueNonNumeric](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-samevaluenonnumeric) algorithm which basically checks if types of compared elements are matching and finally, in the last point of the algorithm it checks:

> If x and y are the same Object value, return true. Otherwise, return false.

My question :

How does `SameValueNonNumeric` algorithm performs the object comparison step? How does it establish that "x and y are the same Object value"? I couldn't find this in specs.

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068834/object-comparison-in-javascript) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201183/how-to-determine-equality-for-two-javascript-objects) question it seems that object comparison is not so straightforward in JS.

Comment: It's basically `a === b` - are they *literally* the same object or not.

Comment: Its nontrivial for every case. How do you compare to objects in general? If 2 objects point to the same instance or when they have the same properties? There is no general answer. So the better question should by WHY do you need that? I feel like comparing objects always indicates a bad approach. Just my personal opinion.

Comment: @Aaron thanks for the comment, I think you nailed it. I wanted to use this function to establish whether in the list of documents (objects) there is already an object with same contents. Seems that it was bad approach, finding object by some unique id will work better. Initially I thought 'includes' will make such 'deep' property-by-property comparison.

Comment: Sometimes you gotta hear somebody elses opinion to re-think your design. Glad it pointed you in the right direction :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are "the same Object value" if they refer to the same block of memory, if you will.

The non-straightforward questions and answers you find are all about how to compare object *contents* in a meaningful manner.

It is very simple to compare objects the "regular" way though, i.e. compare the reference, and that's what `includes` does here too. I agree that the text in `SameValueNonNumber` is a bit unclear at that point, other algorithms specify that more clearly such as [here](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3) at step 1f:

> Return true if x and y **refer to the same object**. Otherwise, return false.

So:

```js
const a = { hello: 'world' }
const b = a
const c = { hello: 'world' }

// Now, a and b refer to the same object, but a/b and c do not.

console.log([a].includes(a)) // true
console.log([a].includes(b)) // true
console.log([a].includes(c)) // false
```

Answer (score 3):

`Array.prototype.includes` is not supposed to give you correct results for object check and is designed to work for Boolean, String and Number values

For an object it basically just does a reference check, so if the object contains same reference as the one in the array, it returns true else just will return false regardless of the values within the object

```js
var arr = [{x: 1, y: 2}, {x: 2, y: 'as'}, {x: 'in', y: 'po'}];
console.log(arr.includes({x: 2, y: 'as'}));
console.log(arr.includes(arr[1]));
```

For object existence check you need to make use of `Array.prototype.find` and check for all values of object

Comment: *Boolean, String and Number* In short, primitives.

Comment: but type of Boolean, String and Number is a function not a primitive, did you mean boolean, number and string?

Comment: Yes, I mean boolean values and not Boolean constructor

Comment: "*is not supposed to give you correct results*" just sounds wrong. It does what it is designed to do, and that is *correct* as defined by the specification.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing it uses the `The Abstract Equality Comparison Algorithm` for determining if the object values are the same.

Specs for the algorithm [here](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3).

Answer (score 0):

Objects and symbols are compared by reference.

We know that `{} === {}` or `Symbol() === Symbol()` both return `false`. Quick example:

```js
console.log([{}].includes({}));
console.log([Symbol()].includes(Symbol()));
```

If they refer to the same "value" i.e. reference, then they'll be equal:

```js
const obj = {};
const sym = Symbol();

console.log([obj].includes(obj));
console.log([sym].includes(sym));
```

Answer (score 0):

`Array.prototype.includes` effectively compares using the `===` operator. So objects are compared by references, primitives by value.

Here's an example comparing `includes` results to `===` results:

```js
const object = {'a': 'b'};
const copyOfObject = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(object));
const array = [object, 'a', 1];

console.table([
    {
        'comparison': 'object vs object',
        'result for Array.prototype.includes': array.includes(object),
        'result for === operator': object === array[0]
    },
    {
        'comparison': 'object vs copyOfObject',
        'result for Array.prototype.includes': array.includes(copyOfObject),
        'result for === operator': object === copyOfObject
    },
    {
        'comparison': 'string "a" vs string "a"',
        'result for Array.prototype.includes': array.includes('a'),
        'result for === operator': 'a' === array[1]
    },
    {
        'comparison': 'string "a" vs string "b"',
        'result for Array.prototype.includes': array.includes('b'),
        'result for === operator': 'b' === array[1]
    },
    {
        'comparison': 'number 1 vs number 1',
        'result for Array.prototype.includes': array.includes(1),
        'result for === operator': 1 === array[2]
    },
    {
        'comparison': 'number 1 vs number 2',
        'result for Array.prototype.includes': array.includes(2),
        'result for === operator': 2 === array[2]
    },

])
```